# Randomly read only 50 % of files

Tags: python

How can I randomly read 50% of the number of files:

```
files = glob.glob("*.txt")

##suppose files are objects

for fi in files:

    #I want to implement through the for loop

    data = np.genfromtxt(fi, ...)
```

Edit: I want to implement through the for loop, in my other problem, the files are object  .

Comment: Random shuffle the file list and iterate over the first half of the elements.

Comment: `random.sample(files, len(files) // 2)`

Comment: I want to implement through the for loop

Comment: @deceze You should post that as an answer; it's better than mine :)

Comment: What does that mean, "want to implement through the for loop"?

Comment: @deceze  supposing files are objects, I cannot use random.sample. But, for loop reads files one by one. So, I want a different mechanism to do it

Comment: It's not really clear how those words go together. Have you tried `for fi in random.sample(files, len(files) // 2): ...` and what's the problem with it, if there is one?

Answer (score 1):

Shuffle the files, then cut the list in half. Here, rounded down:

```py
import random

files = glob.glob("*.txt")
random.shuffle(files)
files = files[:len(files) // 2]

for fi in files:

   data = np.genfromtxt(fi, ...)
```

Comment: I want to implement through the for loop, supposing files are objects